# Blazor Web Assembly Security - Application DLL downloaded

Tags: security, blazor

I have a question regarding Blazor Web Assembly DLL Downloading and security.  It is known that there are tools that can reverse engineer a DLL to get an idea on how the source code functions.  Wouldn't Blazor Wasm model be less secure, since all a potential attacker would need to do is access a Blazor Wasm site for the first time, and pull the DLLs from their local computer to then later analyze them; they wouldn't even need to login?  I would think Blazor Server would be a better option, slower yes, but safer.  Or is assumed that Blazor Wasm is only recommended for sites who do not have high security concerns?

Comment: All Client side code is accessibe to the user. Blazor DLLs are a little bit less accessible than  JavaScript but the principle remains the same. A browser app is never secure.

Comment: To be pedantic, I'd say a browser app's source code is never truly hidden from an end user.